# Cannot Install Scout-app on Windows

Tags: installation

Scout-app (http://scout-app.io/) cannot be installed on Windows. It works on Mac (tested).

I installed through Scout-App application file. i don't know the issue but nothing came. Any idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. That version of Scout-App shipped with a 64-Bit only executable, meaning 32-Bit versions of Windows could not run it. The last two versions of Scout-App that were released were 32-Bit, so they work fine on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows.

If you find bugs like this in the future, report them on the Scout-App issues page so they can be fixed immediately.

- http://github.com/scout-app/scout-app/issues

Latest version available at [Scout-App.io](http://scout-app.io).